# Application launcher that lets me define shortcuts (like DragThing on OS X)

Tags: 10.10, shortcut-keys, gui, launcher

I've just switched to Ubuntu 10.10 from OS X, and the one thing I'm really missing is that I previously had set up a bunch of custom keyboard shortcuts to launch applications. For example, apple-ctrl-f would launch / switch to Firefox.

I've looked around, but I can only find lots of references to Gnome Do, which isn't what I want - I don't want a "type start of application name", launcher, but rather a "explicitly set custom shortcuts" one. Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something like this built into Compiz (the desktop effects engine in Ubuntu). You need `compizconfig-settings-manager` (`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`)to edit the bindings in a nice way though.

Once installed, load it up. It's sitting in System -> Preferences. When it loads up. Click the Commands item.

In there you can specify 12 commands each with their own key, mouse-button and mouse-movement bindings.

There may well be other ways of doing this.. But if you're already running Compiz, this is fairly fast, fairly effective and fairly easy to understand when you know where to find it.

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much what I'm looking for. The only problem now is that when I configure it to launch e.g Firefox, it will always create a new window, whereas I'd like it to bring an existing Firefox window to the foreground if there is one. (I realise this may be a pretty tall order!)

Comment: you might be able to get that addressed on the firefox forums.

Comment: You could have it open a new tab (assuming your tab behaviour is to open in the same window) using this command: `firefox -new-tab http://google.com` or `firefox -new-tab about:blank`